# Django - manytomany relation between User.Profile and another model, ValueError: Cannot add

Tags: python, django, django-models

user/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Bread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/", default="photos/none/default.png")
    bread = models.ManyToManyField(Bread)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I trying to add a simple object to Profile model, but it does not work.

```
>>> from user.models import Bread
>>> from user.models import Profile
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> p1 = Bread(title="Example")
>>> p1.save()
>>> Profile(User).bread.add(p1)
ValueError: Cannot add "<Bread: Example>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
>>> u1 = Profile(User)
>>> u1.save()
TypeError: _prepare() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Seeing similar previous questions I tried to save profile model, as u can see, I know its related with User and his id, but i have no idea how to fix it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to fully create a Profile object and save it before adding Bread instances to it?
Also i notice you're passing a model class to a model constructor. You should pass an instance of a user.
Also your profile model requires some other fields.

I would be rather explicit than implicit in creating it as in:

```
u1 = Profile.objects.create(
    user=myuser,
    bio="blablabla",
    location="blublublue",
)
```

then and only then, i would add the bread instance to the Profile instance

hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from api.models import Film
>>> from user.models import Profile
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
>>> user = get_object_or_404(Profile)
>>> user
<Profile: Profile object>
>>> lobster = get_object_or_404(Film, id=22)
>>> lobster
<Film: Lobster>
>>> a = user.film.add(lobster)
>>> another_movie = get_object_or_404(Film, id=23)
>>> another_movie
<Film: What I actually do>
>>> user.film.add(another_movie)
>>> film = bloader.film.all()
>>> film
<QuerySet [<Film: Lobster>, <Film: What I actually do>]>
>>>
```

I tried like this and Its working, thank you @efkin.